# Does the shuffling of a sequence of measurements produce an i.i.d. sequence?

Tags: probability-theory, queueing-theory

Given a stationary sequence of measurements, say, of response times (i.e., sojourn times), of a queue (e.g., M/M/1), if we randomly reshuffle such samples, will we get a sequence of i.i.d. samples?   If so, how to prove it?

Comment: If you have $n$ measurements and I tell you that $n-1$ are equal to 0 (you don't know which ones), you know for a fact that the last one is either a 0 or a 1. So reshuffling doesn't give you independence.

Comment: thanks, Clement C.  Now, what occurs in the limit when the number of samples tends to infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ of random variables from some joint random distribution. You require this to be stationary: ie for any $k>0$, the joint distribution of $(X_i,\ldots, X_{i+k-1})$ is the same for all $i$.

Now, you randomly shuffle the $X_i$ into a new sequence, say $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots$, and ask if this makes the $Y_i$ independent.

It's not fully clear to me how to shuffle an infinite sequence. The best I can come up with is to take a sequence of length $n$, shuffle this, and then see if the limit is a well-defined probability distribution. For the sake of argument, let's assume it does. *(Maybe someone can elaborate on this?)*

Clement C has already in the comment given an example of how shuffling a finite sequence need not give iid: essentially by taking a joint distribution where the sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is constant. However, this might still result in iid in the limit of $n\rightarrow\infty$.

As a counter-example for an infinite sequence of variables, assume $X_i\sim F_\Theta$ for some random distribution $F_\Theta$ depending on a parameter $\Theta$, where $\Theta$ itself is a random variable. For example, $X_i\sim N(U,\sigma_X^2)$ where $U\sim N(\mu_U,\sigma_U^2)$. This is the kind of models that arise in multi-level models and empirical Bayes. Now, the conditional distribution of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots)|U$, ie conditional on $U$ is iid. However, because of their joint dependence on $U$, the $X_i$ are not iid.

However, the example above, as well as the randomised sequence of observations from your question (if well-defined), are examples of *[exchangable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables)* sequences of variables. This simply means that the distribution is invariant under *any* reordering.

Comment: then, does it follow from de Finetti theorem that, in the limit when the number of samples tends to infinity, the shuffling of a sequence of response times (i.e., sojourn times) from an M/G/1 queue produces a sequence of i.i.d. random variables?

Comment: @DanielS.: At least it would not follow very directly, and for it to follow (by some additional argument), there would have to be a more explicit condition to be satisfied. Intuitively, if as $i$ increases, the dependency between $X_1$ and $X_i$ decreases towards none, iid would follow. In an $M/G/1$ queue with fixed parameters, that should be the case if I'm not mistaken...although don't have a formal statement or proof of that. Stated differently, if the stationary distribution is determined by fixed parameters, and the sequence has limited time memory, it should follow.

Comment: the response times for customers in different busy periods is independent.  Let Xij be the response time of the i-th customer of the j-th busy period.  Then, clearly, Xij is independent of Xkl for l different from j.  Does that suffice to prove that the shuffling produces an i.i.d. sequence?

Comment: @DanielS.: That should be sufficient. *NB: still based on intuition of shuffling $n$ observation as $n$ increases, not formal proof.* There might be some technical requirement to ensure expected length of busy periods are bounded, but that should typically not be a problem.